# Implementing an Auto LogIn link (and ending the session right after that)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

Currently I'm trying to implement an auto login link for the emails sent from the site.

One of the requirements is that the user is able to see the link but not the rest of the site unless he manually logs in.

My current problem is that I cannot get the logout part right. The current flow goes something like this:

1. Check if the user is logged in
2. If not, check the url query string and do some calculation to check
   the code
3. If everything is alright I log the user in, update the CurrentUser
   and all the Session object
4. Then I need to use **HttpContext.Response.Redirect()** because the way
   the system is made *(as far as I have read using Redirect is a quite
   abrupt way to cut the Request, but my current issue is that the
   system will keep checking other things and redirect me to the LogIn
   page if I don't cut it here)*
5. At this point the user is Logged In
6. If they click on a new link inside the page, on this new Request it will check some Session properties
   created on step 4 and if they exist it will log the
   user out.

My problem is that it works some times and some other times it doesn't. A pretty consistent thing I notice is that is not working when I open the link in a new browser instance, but generally works when opening on an already open browser.

I guess something could be happening with the Session object between the Redirect and the new Request specially on a new browser instance, but not sure why.

Edit: The problem is happening on step 6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i totally understand your question, but here are some ideas related to session problems.

Probably when opening the new instance a new Session is created. Therefore your data is gone.

A work around might be storing the needed values in the cache. This is dangerous because cache items can be deleted if iis thinks there is not enough memory.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323290

Another workaround might be saving the needed values in a database.

Or send the needed data through the headers.

Comment: I notice I forgot to say an important part.

Comment: The code that kills the session happens when you click another link on the page (and it starts the auth process again), it will check the sessions properties there.

What is happening is that if I try this on an instance already open it will destroy the session just fine when I click another link (most of the times). 

But if I click the link and open a new instance of the browser it will create this new Session with the Temporary property but for some reason wont keep it when I click another link on the page and fail to end the session.

Comment: Do you use MVC. If so you can add some functions to the global.asax which can help you to see what happens with the session. Everytime a session is created sessionstart is called and when a session is ended session end is called. Here are all the functions that you can check out: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/

Comment: I used the global.asax to log the Session Id and it is always the same, but sometimes the properties are null.

For example myAuthorizationContext.HttpContext.Session["IsTemporary"] = "true" (created on step 4 before calling the Redirect), becomes null on the next Request sometimes.

Comment: I had the same thing not long ago. Took me a week to find. In my case it was a problem width dynamically loading an image width ajax. For some reason it lost all the session data after loading the image. The weird thing was that when i did that with images from another domain it was ok. I never found what the issue was... Maybe it is something you load on the page that is messing the session up.